# css3 spritesheet with scaling

Tags: css, scaling, css-sprites

I generated a CSS Spritesheet with the help of a Texture packer and its looks like

```
.pirateSlotSprite {display:inline-block; overflow:hidden; background-repeat: no-repeat;background-image:url(../img/pirateSlotSprite.png);}
.backgroundps {width:800px; height:480px; background-position: -105px -304px}
.balanceBlockps {width:122px; height:61px; background-position: -0px -0px}

...more classes for each frame...

.lineControlps {width:113px; height:65px; background-position: -580px -0px}
.maxBetButtonps {width:115px; height:64px; background-position: -348px -0px}
```

Then I apply the classes `pirateSlotSprite` and `backgroundps` to a div (sav `bgDiv`) to display the background frame from the sprite sheet. Everything is fine upto this point.

`bgDiv` will get resized when the browser gets resized, but the background picture remained static without getting shrinked/enlarged to fit bgDiv.

So I added `background-size:100%` to `pirateSlotSprite`, but the sprite gets shifted to a different position. I guess the whole image gets shrinked first and then `background-position:-105px -304px` gets applied without the position values being scaled. If needed I will share the pictures to make the problem easier to understand.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Adjust your `background-postion`?

Comment: thats what I am trying to do in JS now... but cant find how exactly to  find the position to translate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You misunderstand the way background images work. Positioning for background-images work with either pixels or percentages. But the images themselves are displayed in their true resolution and aspect ratio (unless altered by JavaScript). So they won't 'scale/stretch' when you resize the browser window.

Comment: wont `background-size:100%` resize the image as and when the div to which it is applied changes it size.. I guess it resizes.. I will post sample code with image to make my problem clear

Comment: Yes, but not in correlation with a background position. Don't get me wrong, in theory this will work. But I don't see a way how you'll be able to calculate the correct positioning and stretching without making the images look bad/incorrectly positioned.

Comment: exactly this is where I am stuck. I dont know how to calculate correct positioning !!!